# How convert html form to javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have html form

```
<form action="https://perfectmoney.com/api/step1.asp" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_ACCOUNT" value="U1224348">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYEE_NAME" value="Perfect Lottery">
<input type="text" name="PAYMENT_ID" value=""><BR>
<input type="text" name="PAYMENT_AMOUNT" value=""><BR>
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_UNITS" value="USD">
<input type="hidden" name="STATUS_URL" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL" value="http://simplecod.wordpress.com/transfers_completed_successfully">
<input type="hidden" name="PAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="LINK">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL" value="http://simplecod.wordpress.com/transfers_will_fail/">
<input type="hidden" name="NOPAYMENT_URL_METHOD" value="LINK">
<input type="hidden" name="SUGGESTED_MEMO" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="time" value="Your bet on 05/23/2011;">
<input type="hidden" name="BAGGAGE_FIELDS" value="time">>
</form>
```

I need to do the same thing in javascript and send the link.

How do this?

Comment: What is your end goal? Because your question is confusing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use jquery, you can use the `serialize()` function which will do exactly what you want. It combines all names and values and generates a string from it.

You can find the function here: http://api.jquery.com/serialize/

Answer (score 0):

not sure about javascript? but you can do this dynamically with a server side script such as Perl or PHP.